# How to reduce the space between text and following enumerate environment?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, itemize

In my lists of items (`enumerate` and `itemize` environments), the space between text and the following list is greater than I want. Is possible reduce this space, and do it throughout the entire document?

I have reduced the space between the items in the list, using

```
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
```

but I would reduce too the space inmediately before this environments.

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to complete small document with your lists (with some dummy text)  which reproduce your problem. Having MWE we can more easy help you.

Comment: I'm far away of my computer, and cannot test it right now. I will try it his evening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your page layout as well used packages (relevant to used lists) are unknow, so we can't reproduce your proble. Please be so kind and consider my comment below question.
- Assume, that your document is close to the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{nosep, topsep=2pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{itemize}
\item   \lipsum[1][1]
\item   \lipsum[1][2]
\item   \lipsum[1][3]
    \end{itemize}
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{enumerate}
\item   \lipsum[1][1]
\item   \lipsum[1][2]
\item   \lipsum[1][3]
    \end{enumerate}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

which compilation produce:

[image]

Is this what you after?

Comment: This is I wanted for!